# VK api login activity

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Привет друзья! Как в VK API сделать свою активити с логином как показано на рисунке 2?
[image: Login VK]

Comment: Это вроде бы запрещено

Comment: Допустим, ну как тогда подобное реализовали к примеру в kate mobil или VK Coffee? Должен же быть какой-то выход :)

Comment: @Brahos, на сколько я знаю, что у первого, что у второго - внутри встроенный браузер, который не работает через VK SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Данный вариант авторизации запрещен, только стандартное окно SDK.

Скорее всего, такое можно достичь или костылем типа скрытого браузера внутри приложения, или будучи каким-то невероятно доверенным приложением для ВКонакте. Тут Вам, скорее всего, поможет поддержка (поможет, а не выдаст такое право :)).

P.S. В свое время, я писал в поддержку ВКонакте и они сказали, что нельзя создавать свое окно авторизации. На вопрос, почему у Kate Mobile есть такое окно, они ответили, что им выдавались права давно и "на других условиях" (что за условия - так и не понял).

Comment: Ну на самом деле подделать браузер в плане логина и получения токена не так уж и сложно, я такое проворачивал на Python)

Comment: @andreymal, я немного преувеличил :). Фактически, это будет обычный REST API клиент.

Comment: @andreymal а можно по подробнее?

Comment: @Brahos нельзя, это типа запрещено и помогать в этом не хочу)

Comment: @andreymal, Вы меня не так поняли... Я хотел спросить, как Вы это сделали (только конкретные запросы или вообще имитировали работу страницы, вплоть до физических нажатий)? Заниматься ничем плохим я не собираюсь, просто интересно.

Answer (score 0):

Доступ к прямой авторизация выдается администрацией ВК. Вот тут написано подробнее: https://vk.com/dev/auth_direct